# Best practice naming strategy for native library locations targetting various processor architectures

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, jna, multiplatform

In many of my java projects there comes a time when I need to add a native dependency. And every time I wonder how to name the installation/extraction locations in a future-proof/extensible way. I look at how other people do it, but I see different naming strategies everywhere.

I'm aware that this is a subjective question, but I would still very much appreciate your input. Just pick any aspect you want to comment on.

My current list (intended to be a work in progress):

```
lib/native/linux-x86/libtest.so
lib/native/linux-x64/libtest.so

lib/native/linux-armel/libtest.so

lib/native/linux-armhl-32bit/libtest.so
lib/native/linux-armhl-64bit/libtest.so (or will armhl libs be like mac dylibs and contain/cover both architectures?)

lib/native/macosx/libtest.dylib (looks like dylibs often contain both x86 and x64 architectures in one file)

lib/native/windows-x86/test.dll
lib/native/windows-x64/test.dll
```

These things I find difficult to decide:

- OS name: win/windows, lin/linux, mac/macosx/osx?
- Processor architecture: IA-32/x86/i386/i586/i686, x86-64/x86_64/x64/amd64?
- 32-bit vs 64-bit: I understand this information is redundant next to the processor architecture but maybe it should be included anyway just for clarity?
- armel/armhl: [This page](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/armv8-architecture.php) seems to indicate that 64-bit ARM processors are compatible with 32-bit components? So maybe there really is no need to distinguish between 32 and 64 bit for armhl?
- Where do things like mips, mipsel, powerpc, ppc, solaris, sparc, itanium/ia64/IA-64 etc. fit into this scheme?
- Do I have to worry about differences between Intel and AMD processors?
- Why do many people use a specific name for the mac os (like macosx), but not for linux/windows identifiers?
- What about mobile phone and tablet processors? Are they already covered by this list?

Most of my "knowledge" about processor architectures I gained from this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125314/109380

Edits:
- 2015-04-08: Removed 32/64 bit identifiers because they seem to be redundant, collapsed the mac 32/64-bit-variants into one line because they can contain both architectures.

Answer (score 1):

JNA has gone through two revisions of naming conventions.

The first simply generated OS Family/CPU Arch pairs based on what Java would produce for `os.name` and `os.arch`, and was loosely based on the host/target triplets used by a lot of GNU software.  In practice, those triplets only have information in the OS and arch components.

The values produced by the JVM are actually pretty inconsistent, which led to version two.

**OS Family** linux, solaris, freebsd, netbsd, darwin (OSX), android

**CPU Arch** x86, x86_64, ppc, ppc64, etc.

The CPU arch is usually sufficient to identify 32- vs 64-bit.

As for ARM variations, I don't have much experience with that in particular but you *do* need to distinguish between hard and soft-float options in your native library and make that explicit.  I don't think it hurts to embed that in the "arch" portion.

I wouldn't worry too much about other variations (mips/mipsel) if you don't anticipate using them in any reasonable timeframe.

powerpc = ppc (ppc64 to distinguish 64-bit)
sunos = solaris (sparc/sparc64 is the arch for sun hardware)
itanium/ia64 = chances are you'll only find one flavor of this, and ia64 suffices for the arch
intel = amd (from Java-land, you're not likely to spot a difference)

Mobile/tablet is going to be primarily android or whatever windows mobile is being called these days, typically with an ARM processor.

"Darwin" is the generic name for OSX, and multiple architectures can be bundled in a single library, so it's often not necessary to distinguish the arch.

Comment: re ARM variations: it's hard to see at a glance, but "armel" and "armhl" are supposed to distinguish between soft and hard.